# Wildcard SSL Certificates for Subdomains on Amazon EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have a single-domain SSL certificate (approx. $9) set up for my domain. Let's call it example.com. This domain is not hosted on Amazon - just a regular web host provider.

Right now, I have an EC2 instance using Route 53 to act as a subdomain. Let's call this a1.example.com.

My question is, what's the best way to go about applying SSL certificates for the a1.example.com subdomain and future subdomains? Will a wildcard SSL certificate help in this situation where all subdomains are hosted on Amazon when the primary domain is not on Amazon?  Do I need to use Amazon's ELB service to accomplish this?  Any specific instructions are helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> question is, what's the best way to go about applying SSL certificates
>   for the a1.example.com subdomain and future subdomains?

The best way depends on how many subdomains you will have, if that's a lot, a wildcard cert will be cheaper.

> Will a wildcard SSL certificate help in this situation where all
>   subdomains are hosted on Amazon when the primary domain is not on
>   Amazon?

Not particularly, the certificate does not care if it is in AWS or not. You can use the same wildcard certificate in separate domains in separate providers.

> Do I need to use Amazon's ELB service to accomplish this?

No, but ELB makes it easier to manage the certificate. You can also use other services that supports SSL (such as CloudFront) or install it on your own server in an EC2 instance.

Comment: To clarify your last sentences, are you saying that a main benefit of using ELB is the ability of ELB to apply the SSL cert to other Amazon Web Services?

Can I just buy one cheap, non-wildcard SSL cert and have ELB apply it to multiple services or instances of EC2, RDS, etc?

Comment: Not at all, the main benefit of using an ELB is having a scalable load balancer as-a-service :) it also support HTTPS, wildcard or not, and it can terminate the SSL connection on the balancer. The connections to EC2 instances behind the ELB can be plain HTTP or HTTPS. RDS is different, it generates its own certificate.

Comment: Thanks, but can I just buy one cheap, non-wildcard SSL cert and have ELB apply it to multiple EC2 instances, then?

Comment: Yes, that is almost it. The wildcard decision is related to the number  of domains, regardless of the number of instances. You can, for example, have ten instances answering for a single domain name, with a single certificate and a single load balancer, with HTTPS terminating on the ELB.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying futher, but my question is can ELB work as a "proxy" to apply a single SSL certificate to properly secure an unlimited amount of domains and subdomains since the SSL certificate is applied to ELB itself?

Comment: Yes, but for unlimited subdomains you will need the wildcard. For example, you can have a.mydomain.com and b.mydomain.com pointing to the same ELB with the certificate for *.mydomain.com installed. For the ELB, it won't even matter if the certificate is wildcard or not, as the verification is performed by the browser.

Comment: And ELB won't be able to route traffic depending on the domain. It will send all traffic to 1 (group of) instance(s).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add my understanding for future readers:

The SSL certificate itself determines the domain(s) for which the certificate is valid.  If you buy a $9 SSL certificate, ELB can attempt to apply it any way you specify through ELB, however, the domains themselves will not be validated by the SSL certificate because the SSL certificate may not be encrypted for use with the intended domain(s).  Although ELB is used to apply the certificate, it is not used to authenticate the SSL certificate (only the domain does this), so the "blanket" idea in the original post will not work.